# If one Cron Job fails, carry on to next job

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi, cron-task

I've set up my Crontab to execute a selection of Python scripts in order to interrogate a solar inverter and upload the results to PVOutput:

```
*/5 * * * * cd /home/Pi/; python pvout_upload.py;
*/5 * * * * cd /home/Pi/; python weather.py;
```

The problem is if the internet goes down, then those scripts fail. 
So I've created another script that reads the inverter and stores the result to a local database that can be uploaded later. But if there's no internet, then those previous Cron-task fail and the Python script won't run either.

Is there a way to have Cron-task carry on to the next line if one fails?

Comment: AFAIK, cron jobs start in your HOME directory so there is no need to change directory to there. AFAIK, each line/job in your crontab is independent of the others, so I think your assumptions need revisiting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use classical shell resources for this. If you put

```
command1 || command2
```

in your crontab line. Then:

command2 will be executed if command1 fails (returns an error)
It would be something like:

```
*/5 * * * * cd /home/Pi/; python pvout_upload.py || python errorManagement.py
```

Of course, you could also embed this logic in your python script.